# Handling Optional Arguments in bash

Tags: bash, options

I have the following function that is supposed to write strings in new lines.  There is a warning option, so that when `-w` is set by the user, some lines get coloured in red.  `-w` allows an optional numeric argument `-wNUM`.  If `NUM` is not provided, `warn` is set to `1` so that only the first line is coloured red.

I am encountering a problem with calling the command

`printfm -w -- "First line" "second line"`).

I have included `local warn="1"` before the `case` statement.

```
  ("-w"|"--warning")
     local warn="1"
     case "$2" in
```

The function is listed here

```
printfm ()
{
  # Process command line options
  shortopts="hVw::"
  longopts="help,version,warning::"

  opts=$(getopt -o "$shortopts" -l "$longopts" -n "${0##*/}" -- "$@")

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    local shorthelp=1  # getopt returned (and reported) an error.
    return
  fi

  local f=0
  
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "set -- ${opts}"
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
      case "$1" in
        ("-V"|"--version")
          printf "%s\n" "V01 Jul 2021 Wk27"
          declare -i f=0
          shift
          break
          ;;
        ("-h"|-\?|"--help")
          printf "%s\n" "Print strings."
          declare -i f=0
          shift
          break
          ;;
        # ------------------------------------
        ("-w"|"--warning")
          case "$2" in
            (+([[:digit:]])) 
              local -r warn="$2"
              shift 2
              ;;
            (*) 
              local -r warn="1"
              shift 2
              ;;
            esac
            declare -i local f=1
            ;;
          # ----------------------------------------
          (--)
            declare -i local f=1
            shift
            break
            ;;
        esac
      done
    fi

    red=$(tput setaf 9)  
    rgl=$(tput sgr0)
  
    # Print normal text or warnings
  
    if [[ -v $f ]] && (( f != 0 )); then

      # print normal multi-line text
      [[ ! -v $warn ]] && printf '%s\n' "$@"

      # print multi-line warnings

      rge='^[0-9]+$'
      if [[ -v $warn && "$warn" == "1" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' ${red}"$1"${rgl}  # first line red
        printf '%s\n' "${@:2}"          # remaining, uncoloured
      elif [[ -v $warn && "$warn" =~ $rge ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' ${red}"$@"${rgl}  # all lines red
      fi

    fi
    return 0
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to actually ask a question. What is it you need here? Are you trying to understand why the strings are not printed? If so, we would need to know how you call the script. All we have is the function, not the rest of the script and we don't know how you are running it. By the way, `-n warn ` is testing the string _warn_, not the variable `$warn` so that will always be true.

Comment: The function itself has a syntax error. Have you tried running it? Do you not get `line 36: syntax error near unexpected token '('` and `line 36: '            (+([[:digit:]])) '`?

Comment: I have been running `printfm -w -- "Line 1" "Line 2"` and `printfm -w2 -- "Line 1" "Line 2"`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) ask something; ii) include what shell you are running this in. In bash, you should get a syntax error with what you have posted. Finally, iii) when asking, it is really helpful to first debug and isolate the problem. We don't need to understand ~80 lines of code to help you, all we need is a few lines that can reproduce the issue. This is also the first step in any debugging process: start removing things until you can find the minimal code that reproduces the problem so we don't waste time looking at irrelevant parts.

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `(+([[:digit:]]))`? Specifically the `+`?

Comment: `(+([[:digit:]]))` is supposed to be a pattern that matches a numeric value.

Comment: `warn` is being set correctly, ether `1` when `-w` is used or `NUM` when `-wNUM` is used.

Comment: `+(pattern)` is equivalent to `(regex)+`.

Comment: Try it. Compare `unset warn; if [[ -n $warn ]]; then echo "not empty"; fi` and `unset warn; if [[ -n warn ]]; then echo "not empty"; fi`.

Comment: I shall change to `[[ -v warn &&`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127843/discussion-between-terdon-and-pietru).

Comment: How is this different from you previous question ([options with optional values using getopt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659502)) and did you not get any help from the answer there?

Comment: This puts the complete code rather than just a part.  This one is just focused on the problem of using `printfm -w -- "Line 1" "Line2"`.

Comment: Please point to the pattern in your case statement that explicitly matches the **single** argument `-w2`.

Comment: I have been thinking of adding `local -r warn="1"` just before the case statement `case "$2" in`.  Single argument can be matched by tho pattern `+([[:digit:]])`.